# How to scale one view to another

Tags: android

How do you scale one view to another? I tried finding scale x and scale y by dividing the width and height of each view, but it doesn't return the right value.

Scale a -> b.

```
a.setPivotX(0);
a.setPivotY(0);
a.setScaleX(b.getWidth() / a.getWidth())
a.setScaleY(b.getHeight() / a.getHeight())
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: Please write complete code....

Comment: @pskink @thestalker View `a` is smaller than view `b`. I would like to scale `a `to the same size as `b`.

Comment: are a and b the children of the same layout? if so, what kind of Layout?

Comment: @pskink Yes. `FrameLayout`.

Comment: `FrameLayout`s lay out its children to have the same size by default

Answer (score 0):

firstly, you should call `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` after the view is be measured maybe after `onResume()`. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/getwidth-and-getheight-of-view-returns-0) maybe helpful

secondly, `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` return int, int/int will get a int but not a float. you may do like this `(float) getWidth() / getHeight()`.

sorry for my poor English.